# Corrupted array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
char arr[10]="\0",arr1[2][5]={'\0'};
cout<<"enter the full line : ";
gets(arr);
for (int i=0;i<1;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        if(j<=4)
        {
                arr1[0][j]=arr[j] ;
        }
        else if (j>4)
                {
                    arr1[1][j-5]=arr[j] ;
                }
        }
}

    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        cout<<arr1[0][j]<<" ";
    }

cout<<endl;
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        cout<<arr1[1][j]<<" ";
    }
```

Here what i am trying to do is converting a 1d array in to 2d array.
my main purpose is to store 1d array on a 2d and when the first row is completed it should shift the string to next row it is doing all the as i have declared the arr[10] and inputting 10 charcter string through get(arr) it is storing the array as i want but at the end displays an error window i dont know why the program is running perfect as well as giving this error window 
my input : hanzlaamja (10charcters)

my output:
h a n z l
a a m j a

according to my wish but the main problem is the error window.

note : there is nothing in error box or warning box.

My program is working perfectly, but i am getting an error of array corruption.

Can anybody help me out?  I would be very thankful
[please see this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0iKo.png)

[full picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDNFT.png)

Comment: Please include the error message and where are you getting it (which line)

Comment: `(int i=0;i<1;i++)` why

Comment: What is the input, and what output do you get? And what does "corrupt" actually mean in this case?

Comment: *my program is working perfect* -- It is?  Then why are you having issues with the array being corrupted?

Comment: i m not getting any error message

Comment: 1) "_my program is working perfect but i am getting an error of arr currupt_" These are contradictory statements: it **can't** both work correctly, and corrupt memory. 2) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? 3) Please provide [mcve] **including** the input that you are using. It would corrupt memory if you entered a string longer than 9 characters.

Comment: `gets` doesn't even exist anymore because of how unsafe it is. `std::getline` is the recommended approach to reading a line of input.

Comment: In the comments you say "_i m not getting any error message_", but in the question you say "_ i am getting an error_". Unclear what you are asking for. What is the problem??

Comment: Please post the text of the error dialog box instead of a link to an image of the dialog box.

Comment: please see the pic sir recently added

Comment: sir error dialog box is empty

Comment: The error is most likely caused by inputting a string that is larger than 9 characters. Please post the input you used to get the error.

Comment: @HanzlaAmjad -- Please don't post images.  Having said that, the dialog is telling you that your program does not work perfect.   You see it for yourself, so why claim it is working perfect?  We need to see your input you're using.  That program easily is corrupted with a string >= 10 characters being entered.

Comment: i have posted the complete screenshot i hope this will help you better in understanding my question :)

Comment: @HanzlaAmjad 1) Did you read my comment? Please post [mcve], **including** the input you used, since length of that, is most likely the cause of the problem. 2) Again, **don't** post screenshots - **copy-paste** relevant information into the question.

Comment: so i have to enter only 9 characters ?

Comment: You seem to like writing loops that execute exactly once, which is very pointless.

Comment: yes @molbdnilo got your point and removed them thanks :)

Comment: @HanzlaAmjad -- Your loops are totally unnecessary.  A 2D array stores its data in contiguous memory, so you don't even need to know how many rows there are.  All you need is to know the maximum number of characters you need to copy over to the 2D array.  [Please see this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0692cd654867d260).  A single line of code is all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you read in 10 characters (e.g. "hanzlaamja") *and* the string termination character `'\0'`, which is automatically added by `gets`. Thereby you  exceed array bounds, as this would require space for `11` characters. So it would already work if you wrote `char arr[11];`. But as mentioned in the comments, do not use `gets`; it  is unsafe  and it does not prevent you from  exceeding array bounds. The following snippet shows how to do this part better:

```
...
char arr[11]="\0",arr1[2][5]={'\0'};
cout<<"enter the full line : ";
//    gets(arr);
if (!fgets(arr,11,stdin)) {
    cout << "no value read." << endl;
    return 1;
}
...
```

A lot of your loops could be written shorter / better readable. But that's not the actual topic.

Comment: got your point let me try thanks

Comment: thank you so much sir thanks for this help

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the great point pointed out by ***@Stephan Lechner***, I have composed a solution "as close as possible" to your original.

Compiled under visual studio 2017.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "main - start" << endl;
    const size_t numOfRows = 2;
    const size_t numOfCol = 5;
    const size_t numCharsInSingleDimArray = 10;
    char arr[numCharsInSingleDimArray] = { '\0' }, arr1[numOfRows][numOfCol] = { '\0' };

    cout << "enter the full line : ";
    gets_s(arr);    // Note:If the buffer (arr) is too small to contain the input line and null terminator, these functions invoke an invalid parameter handle.  
    cout << "main - entered:" << arr << endl;
    char* twoDimArrStartLoc = &(arr1[0][0]);  // as user4581301  pointed out, it is also possible to "approach" it by treating the two dimensional array as a contiguous bytes in memory
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0;  i< numCharsInSingleDimArray; ++i, ++j)
    {
        twoDimArrStartLoc[j] = arr[i];
    }

    cout << "main - after converting the 1d array into 2d array, arr1 is:" << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numOfRows; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < numOfCol; ++j)
        {
            cout << "arr1[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]:" << arr1[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    } 

    // for debug - you can remove this if not needed...
    cout << "main - end, enter any key and press enter to terminate..." << endl;
    char tmp;
    cin >> tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers,

Guy.

Comment: There is no need to even write a nested loop to populate the 2D array,  Since the 2D array is in contiguous memory, all you need is one loop and not even care how many rows there are.  See my comments above in the main section.

Comment: `gets_s(arr);    // Note: Using this function will prevent you from entering more than 9 characters for your input string.` The comment is untrue. This simply better defines what will happen if you input too many characters. It is only marginally better than `gets`. In addition, `gets_s` typically needs an additional parameter: The length of the buffer. It appears MSVC has a non-standard overload.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - You are right, yet in my solution I tried to implement it "as near as possible" to the original solution only for convenience purposes. I agree that a more simple and elegant solution is appropriate here.

Comment: @user4581301 - Thanks for commenting that out. I changed the comment to a more "precise one" (which was my original intention). Regarding the `size` argument - form the MSDN doc: `In C++, using these functions is simplified by template overloads; the overloads can infer buffer length automatically (eliminating the need to specify a size argument)` - so it is not mandatory, yet I agree that for clarity it is better to use the version of this method that DOES take the `size`  argument. Again, thanks for pointing these notes.

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone for your support the MAIN mistake i was doing is the use of gets(arr) and doing arr[10] as if you are using  function gets(arr) you have to give one extra index which is used by this function gets(arr) i.e. arr[11]
solved :)